# How to cross compile from Mac to Linux?

Tags: macos, ubuntu, rust, rust-cargo

I wrote a little game using Rust, and I used `cargo build --release` to compile a release version on Mac.

I tried to share this with my friend who is using Ubuntu, but when he tried to run the binary, he got the following error:

```
cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

I searched for this but found no answers. Doesn't Rust claim to have "no runtime"? Shouldn't it be able to run anywhere in binary form?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Rust not having a runtime means that it doesn't have a lot of code running as part of the language (for example a garbage collector or bytecode interpreter).  It does still need to use operating system primitives (i.e. syscalls), and these are different on MacOS and Linux.

What you want is a cross compiler.  If you're using `rustup`, then [installing a cross compiler](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/rustup.rs/#cross-compilation) should be simple:

```
# Install the toolchain to build Linux x86_64 binaries
rustup target add x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
```

Then building is:

```
cargo build --release --target=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
```

Caveat: I don't have an OS X machine to test this on; please comment or edit to fix this if it works!

Comment: I tried, I think you might have to install `x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc` then add a `linker` to `.cargo/config` to make that work.

Comment: @FrontMage -- how do you install `x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc` on Mac?

Comment: This does not produce a binary: `error: linking with \`cc\` failed:` ... `= note: clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-pie' [-Wunused-command-line-argument] ld: unknown option: --as-needed clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Comment: @Shepmaster i have the same issue while compiling from linux to mac do you have any idea about the solution ?

Comment: `brew install rustup-init && rustup-init`

Comment: @Shepmaster you may need to install the linker, `brew install FiloSottile/musl-cross/musl-cross` or `brew install gcc`, and add it to `.cargo/config`

Comment: Ses also https://github.com/messense/homebrew-macos-cross-toolchains

Answer (score 4):

Well, it is *because* Rust has no runtime (unlike e.g. Java's JVM) that you can't just compile code on one OS and expect it to run on a different one; what you are looking for is [cross-compilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler). I haven't done it in Rust, but from what I can gather you can find relevant information on different cross-compilation Rust strategies on this [GitHub repo](https://github.com/japaric/rust-cross).